# AWS personalize service not available using boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-personalize

I am trying to setup a boto3 client to use the AWS personalize service along the lines of what is done here:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/personalize/latest/dg/data-prep-importing.html

I have faithfully followed the tutorial up to this point. I have my s3 bucket set up, and I have an appropriately formatted csv.

I configured my access and secret tokens and can successfully perform basic operations on my s3 bucket, so I think that part is working:

```
import s3fs
fs = s3fs.S3FileSystem()
fs.ls('personalize-service-test')
'personalize-test/data'
```

When I try to create my service, things start to fail:

```
import boto3
personalize = boto3.client('personalize')

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnknownServiceError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-c23d30ee6bd1> in <module>
----> 1 personalize = boto3.client('personalize')

/anaconda3/envs/ds_std_3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/boto3/__init__.py in client(*args, **kwargs)
     89     See :py:meth:`boto3.session.Session.client`.
     90     """
---> 91     return _get_default_session().client(*args, **kwargs)
     92 
     93 

/anaconda3/envs/ds_std_3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/boto3/session.py in client(self, service_name, region_name, api_version, use_ssl, verify, endpoint_url, aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key, aws_session_token, config)
    261             aws_access_key_id=aws_access_key_id,
    262             aws_secret_access_key=aws_secret_access_key,
--> 263             aws_session_token=aws_session_token, config=config)
    264 
    265     def resource(self, service_name, region_name=None, api_version=None,

/anaconda3/envs/ds_std_3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/session.py in create_client(self, service_name, region_name, api_version, use_ssl, verify, endpoint_url, aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key, aws_session_token, config)
    836             is_secure=use_ssl, endpoint_url=endpoint_url, verify=verify,
    837             credentials=credentials, scoped_config=self.get_scoped_config(),
--> 838             client_config=config, api_version=api_version)
    839         monitor = self._get_internal_component('monitor')
    840         if monitor is not None:

/anaconda3/envs/ds_std_3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/client.py in create_client(self, service_name, region_name, is_secure, endpoint_url, verify, credentials, scoped_config, api_version, client_config)
     77             'choose-service-name', service_name=service_name)
     78         service_name = first_non_none_response(responses, default=service_name)
---> 79         service_model = self._load_service_model(service_name, api_version)
     80         cls = self._create_client_class(service_name, service_model)
     81         endpoint_bridge = ClientEndpointBridge(

/anaconda3/envs/ds_std_3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/client.py in _load_service_model(self, service_name, api_version)
    115     def _load_service_model(self, service_name, api_version=None):
    116         json_model = self._loader.load_service_model(service_name, 'service-2',
--> 117                                                      api_version=api_version)
    118         service_model = ServiceModel(json_model, service_name=service_name)
    119         return service_model

/anaconda3/envs/ds_std_3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/loaders.py in _wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
    130         if key in self._cache:
    131             return self._cache[key]
--> 132         data = func(self, *args, **kwargs)
    133         self._cache[key] = data
    134         return data

/anaconda3/envs/ds_std_3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/loaders.py in load_service_model(self, service_name, type_name, api_version)
    376             raise UnknownServiceError(
    377                 service_name=service_name,
--> 378                 known_service_names=', '.join(sorted(known_services)))
    379         if api_version is None:
    380             api_version = self.determine_latest_version(

UnknownServiceError: Unknown service: 'personalize'. Valid service names are: acm, acm-pca, alexaforbusiness, amplify, apigateway, apigatewaymanagementapi, apigatewayv2, application-autoscaling, appmesh, appstream, appsync, athena, autoscaling, autoscaling-plans, backup, batch, budgets, ce, chime, cloud9, clouddirectory, cloudformation, cloudfront, cloudhsm, cloudhsmv2, cloudsearch, cloudsearchdomain, cloudtrail, cloudwatch, codebuild, codecommit, codedeploy, codepipeline, codestar, cognito-identity, cognito-idp, cognito-sync, comprehend, comprehendmedical, config, connect, cur, datapipeline, datasync, dax, devicefarm, directconnect, discovery, dlm, dms, docdb, ds, dynamodb, dynamodbstreams, ec2, ecr, ecs, efs, eks, elasticache, elasticbeanstalk, elastictranscoder, elb, elbv2, emr, es, events, firehose, fms, fsx, gamelift, glacier, globalaccelerator, glue, greengrass, guardduty, health, iam, importexport, inspector, iot, iot-data, iot-jobs-data, iot1click-devices, iot1click-projects, iotanalytics, kafka, kinesis, kinesis-video-archived-media, kinesis-video-media, kinesisanalytics, kinesisanalyticsv2, kinesisvideo, kms, lambda, lex-models, lex-runtime, license-manager, lightsail, logs, machinelearning, macie, marketplace-entitlement, marketplacecommerceanalytics, mediaconnect, mediaconvert, medialive, mediapackage, mediastore, mediastore-data, mediatailor, meteringmarketplace, mgh, mobile, mq, mturk, neptune, opsworks, opsworkscm, organizations, pi, pinpoint, pinpoint-email, pinpoint-sms-voice, polly, pricing, quicksight, ram, rds, rds-data, redshift, rekognition, resource-groups, resourcegroupstaggingapi, robomaker, route53, route53domains, route53resolver, s3, s3control, sagemaker, sagemaker-runtime, sdb, secretsmanager, securityhub, serverlessrepo, servicecatalog, servicediscovery, ses, shield, signer, sms, sms-voice, snowball, sns, sqs, ssm, stepfunctions, storagegateway, sts, support, swf, textract, transcribe, transfer, translate, waf, waf-regional, workdocs, worklink, workmail, workspaces, xray
```

Indeed the service name 'personalize' is missing from the list.

I already tried upgrading `boto3` and `botocore` to their latest version and restarting my kernel.

```
boto3           1.9.143 
botocore        1.12.143
```

Any idea as to what to try next would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had neglected to perform these setup steps:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/personalize/latest/dg/aws-personalize-set-up-aws-cli.html

When I did that and restarted my kernel, boto3 picked up the service definition and now things seem to work.

Answer (score 3):

Have you signed up for the preview through the [landing page](https://aws.amazon.com/personalize/)? Personalize is still in limited preview, so your account will not be able to access it through `boto3` by default, unless otherwise whitelisted.

Edit: Personalize is currently publicly available, so this answer is no longer relevant.

Answer (score 3):

The [boto3 documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/index.html) does not (currently on 1.9.143) list `personalize` as a supported service.